# Programmatically adding routes to Backbone.Router?

Tags: backbone.js, routes, backbone-routing

Here is my `application-router.js` file where i'm creating `Backbone.Router` object with just only few routes:

```
var App = App || {};

App.Router =  Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        ''      : 'showDashboard', // Not shown
        '*other': 'showModalError'
    },
    defaultRoute : function(other) { $('#modal404').modal(); }
});
```

In main javascript file `application.js` i'd like to programmatically add routes. I've tried with [route()](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-route) function and it doesn't work, routes are not added. It works however passing an object to the "constructor", but that will override already defined routes:

```
// This works and overrides all defined routes in App.Router
var router = new App.Router({ routes : { '/test/me' : 'testRoute' } });

// This is not working
router.route(ExposeTranslation.get('customers.new.route'), 'newCustomer');
router.route('/test/me/again', 'testAgainRoute');
```

In fact `console.log(App.Router)` shows:

```
routes Object { /test/me="testRoute"}
```

I suppose i'm missing something i can't figure out, i'm beginning learning this little piece of powerful javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `router.route` calls are working, those calls aren't your problem. When you call [`route`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) to add a new route, the new route goes at the end of the routing list. In particular, the routes that are added by your `route` calls go after `'*other'` and `'*other'` will match anything so your new routes will be effectively ignored.

Try removing your `'*other'` route from `routes` and adding it after your two `route()` calls:

```
routes : {
    ''      : 'showDashboard' // Not shown
},

router.route(ExposeTranslation.get('customers.new.route'), 'newCustomer');
router.route('/test/me/again', 'testAgainRoute');
router.route('*other', 'showModalError');
```

The routes aren't stored in `App.Router` object, [they're stored inside `Backbone.history`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L1237):

```
route: function(route, name, callback) {
  // ...
  Backbone.history.route(route, _.bind(function(fragment) {
    //...
  }, this));
  return this;
},
```

That's why your `console.log(App.Router)` doesn't say anything helpful.